Why virtual memory usage is not a concern for 64bit system?
I came across a statement in Perfetto, the official Android profiler, that says: 'When optimizing memory use of programs, we are interested in reducing their footprint in physical memory. High virtual memory use is generally not a cause for concern on modern platforms (except if you run out of address space, which is very hard on 64-bit systems).' https://perfetto.dev/docs/case-studies/memory
However, virtual memory is still a form of memory usage, isn't it? The app doesn't know what they allocate virtual/physical memory.
For example, if an app is using 50GB of virtual memory, doesn't that imply the app has allocated 50GB and never deallocated it, which could be problematic? Why wouldn't this be a concern? How can we trust if or when the system will swap out unused memory pages?

No, virtual memory is not a form of memory. It's more like an address in a street, which can but doesn't have to contain a house.

I think the idea is that you can hold that memory, but the stale/unused bits will be in virtual ram and just the active bits will be in the physical memory. Classically in windows once you hit the swap file it's performance was so bad, it was pretty much a way to save your work and close the programs. So you're correct 50GB is allocated and not able to be released, but that doesn't necessarily mean you need to worry about the memory. Unless you have a leak and it keeps growing. The recap in your link seems to agree.

@matt Thanks Matt. For general memory usage optimization, my confusion is that should the developer optimize memory usage in general or just for physical memory? If so, how does the developer gonna know what part of their allocation is swapped to disk instead of on physical disk?

I think you should worry more about memory leaks, and making sure references properly go out of scope first. Then this seems to say you don't have to worry about using caches because Android will automatically cache objects you're not using. So if there are objects that are expensive create, but you don't need them for awhile, you can keep a reference. If the physical memory consumption is too large, then you're maybe you're accessing those objects too much so you have a couple ways to optimize.

I would write an answer, but it probably isn't useful unless somebody who is versed in andoid memory management can explain, I am just going by what the linked article says.
